# mkdocs: How to link to the same images in ./README.md and ./docs/INDEX.md at the same time?

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

I have a `README.md` file in my project's root folder. The `README.md` contains links to images like this:

```
![image.jpeg](docs/media/image.jpeg)
```

Now, in my `docs` folder, I have my `index.md` file referencing my `README.md` as follows (making use of `mkdocs`'s `pymdownx.snippets` extension):

```
--8<-- "README.md"
```

The issue is that the link to the images is not correct anymore. There doesn't exist a `/docs/docs/` folder. As a result, `mkdocs` isn't able to find the images.

I am wondering how to change the links to, let's say, always start at the root of the project?